# MySQL - query for sorting

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Example data:

```
username score  time
-------- -----  ----
jim        90     50
jim        90     30
paul       50     30
bob       100     90
tim        90     20
```

I want to be able to sort by score in descending order. If two scores are the same, sort by the lowest time.  If there are multiple rows with the same username, I only want one.  So the above table should look like this:

```
username  score  time
--------  -----  ----
bob         100    90
tim          90    20
jim          90    30
paul         50    30
```

I have a query that nearly produces this, however, if the scores are the same, it doesn't sort by lowest time. How would I do this?

```
SELECT U.username, S.score, S.time
FROM scores S JOIN users U ON S.user_id=U.user_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM scores R2 WHERE R2.user_id = S.user_id and R2.score_id > S.score_id
)
AND test_id=0
AND module_id=1
ORDER BY score DESC, time ASC;
```

Comment: The order by looks like it should. I can't imagine why it wouldn't work. Can you describe in more detail what your current output is?

Comment: The order by looks good to me too. Is your time column numeric or character? If it's character then values like 10 and 100 would sort lower than values like 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoiding using a sub query and using a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead.:-

```
SELECT U.username, s1.score, s1.time
FROM scores s1
INNER JOIN users U 
ON s1.user_id = U.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN scores s2
ON s1.user_id = s2.user_id
AND (s1.score < s2.score
OR (s1.score = s2.score
AND s1.time > s2.time))
WHERE s2.user_id IS NULL
ORDER BY s1.score DESC, s1.time ASC
```

This does a LEFT OUTER JOIN against the score table looking for a match for the same user with a higher score, or the same score and a faster time. Any where these are found are not the best score so are dropped with the WHERE clause

SQL fiddle for this:-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f3e93/3

Edit - adding the test_id and module_id checks if required:-

```
SELECT U.username, s1.score, s1.time
FROM scores s1
INNER JOIN users U 
ON s1.user_id = U.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN scores s2
ON s1.user_id = s2.user_id
AND s2.test_id = 0
AND s2.module_id = 1
AND (s1.score < s2.score
OR (s1.score = s2.score
AND s1.time > s2.time))
WHERE s2.user_id IS NULL
AND s1.test_id = 0
AND s1.module_id = 1
ORDER BY s1.score DESC, s1.time ASC
```

Comment: Thanks. You missed out the 'AND test_id=0 AND module_id=1' but I guess I can add that just above the 'ORDER BY' line.

Comment: Also needed in the ON clause for the LEFT JOINed table. Will edit the answer for that.

Comment: I don't understand why you've done an INNER JOIN and a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: The INNER JOIN is to get the username of the score / time retrieved. The LEFT JOIN is used to ensure that there is no higher rated score / time. Any score where there is a higher rated score / time will have a user id on S2 that is not null, and these are dropped by th WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT U.username, max(S.score) as maxscore, min(S.time) as mintime
FROM scores S 
JOIN users U ON S.user_id=U.user_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
   SELECT 1 FROM scores R2 
   WHERE R2.user_id = S.user_id and R2.score_id > S.score_id
)
AND test_id=0
AND module_id=1
GROUP BY U.username
ORDER BY maxscore DESC, mintime ASC;
```